# Bayes theorem probability question

Tags: probability

I have a simple question: what is the difference, if at all, between

$$
P(A|X,Y)
$$

and

$$
P(A|X\And Y)
$$

and what form would these two take if represented using bayes theorem? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$, $X$ and $Y$ are events then I would read them as being the same.

You have $$\Pr(A|X,Y) = \dfrac{\Pr(X,Y|A)\Pr(A)}{\Pr(X,Y)}$$ (assuming the denominator is positive) which you can also write many different ways, such as $$\Pr(A|X,Y) = \dfrac{\Pr(X|A,Y)\Pr(Y|A)\Pr(A)}{\Pr(X|Y)\Pr(Y)}.$$